# trim Array in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I Have an array say

```
['(','C','1','2',')']
```

Now I want to trim data from array beginning from `indexOf('C') + 2` ,If it is a digit I need to remove it from array.. So for the above example final array has to be

```
 ['(','C','1',')']
```

For example if I have `['(','C','1','2','3','*',')']` I want it to be trimmed to `['(','C','1','*',')']` , After element 'C' only one numeral is allowed.

I know I can traverse the array by getting the indexOf('C') and then checking each element for numeric.. but help me with some efficient and better way. like using splice or something.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [**Array.slice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) ??

Comment: Traversing the array is not anymore inefficient than using `.splice()` or something.... Since you would have to have used `.indexOf()` to get the indices to do the *splice*. Another method is *joining* the array back into a *String* and performing **regex** matching.

Comment: @sweetamylase—joining and using a regular expression may work in trivial cases (per the OP), but where the data is a random string it's very difficult. Regular expressions aren't good for parsing irregular data (even fairly ordered irregular data, like markup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the position from where you want to 'trim' is known, you could use `filter` here, like.:

```
var a = ['(','C','1','2','3','*',')']
        .filter( function(a){
                   this.x += 1; 
                   return this.x<=2 ? a : isNaN(+a);}, {x:-1} 
         );
```

Which could lead to this `Array` extension:

```
Array.prototype.trimNumbersFrom = function(n){ 
    return this.filter( function(a){
                         this.x += 1; 
                         return this.x<=n ? a : isNaN(+a);
                        }, {x:-1} 
           );
};
//=> usage
var a = ['(','C','1','2','3','*',')'].trimNumbersFrom(2);
    //=> ["(", "C", "1", "*", ")"]
```

[**See also ...**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: i tried Array.prototype.trimNumbersFrom  but its not workin fine for just one case ... ["(", "C", "1", "0"] ...

Comment: Yep, `!+a` returns `true` for '0'. `IsNaN(+a)` doesn"t, edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = ['(','C', 'a', '8','2',')'].join("").split("C");
var nPos = a[1].search(/[0-9]/g);
var firstNumber = a[1][nPos];
var b = a[1].split(n);

// rebuild
a = a[0] + "C" + b[0] + firstNumber + b[1].replace(/[0-9]/g, "");
```

Not tested thoroughly but for your case it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use of [isNaN()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp) function which returns false if its a valid number or true if it's not a number

```
var str = ['(','C','1','2','3','4','*',')']; // Your Input
var temp = [],count = 0;

for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
{
   if(i<str.indexOf('C') + 2)
   {
      temp[count] = str[i];
      count++;
   }
   else
   {
      if(isNaN(str[i]) == true)
      {
        temp[count] = str[i];
        count++;
      }      
   }
 }
str = temp;
alert(str);
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yexWg/)

Comment: ur solution is perfect .. even i was doin the same ... was jst lukin for some more efficient way.. thanks ....