# Trim varying sized array (but always over 20) down to specific length (10)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I'm working with an array that has a bunch of items, always over 20, but never the same amount. I want to trim that array to just 10 items. [The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15608789/144785) doesn't take into account varying sized arrays.

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: Until you give more specifics as to any criterion for what to keep, or show some code, I'm going with: `array.slice(0, 10)`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fslice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice an array with [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) :

```
new_array = old_array.slice(0,10);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8PcdA/)

Comment: That was too easy. Thanks adeneo!

Answer (score 2):

This trims the array in place:

```
arr.length = 10;
```